# Google test not working

Tags: linker, cmake, googletest, archlinux, clion

I'm on Arch Linux, cloned the gtest repo, cmake-ed google test and installed. The result are as follows:

```
- Install configuration: ""
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libgmock.a
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libgmock_main.a
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-generated-actions.h.pump
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-cardinalities.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-more-actions.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-generated-actions.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-more-matchers.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-actions.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-generated-matchers.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-generated-function-mockers.h.pump
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-generated-matchers.h.pump
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-generated-nice-strict.h.pump
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-generated-nice-strict.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock-generated-function-mockers.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock/internal
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock/internal/gmock-generated-internal-utils.h.pump
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock/internal/custom
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock/internal/custom/gmock-matchers.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock/internal/custom/gmock-generated-actions.h.pump
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock/internal/custom/gmock-generated-actions.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock/internal/custom/gmock-port.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock/internal/gmock-generated-internal-utils.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock/internal/gmock-port.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock/internal/gmock-internal-utils.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gmock/gmock.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libgtest.a
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/libgtest_main.a
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest_prod.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest-param-test.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest-param-test.h.pump
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest-spi.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest-test-part.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest-typed-test.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest-message.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest-death-test.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest_pred_impl.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-param-util-generated.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-param-util-generated.h.pump
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/custom
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/custom/gtest.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/custom/gtest-printers.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/custom/gtest-port.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-type-util.h.pump
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-string.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-type-util.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-linked_ptr.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port-arch.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-death-test-internal.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-tuple.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-filepath.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-tuple.h.pump
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-param-util.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h
```

Checking linkage gives me:

```
[user@machine]$ sudo ldconfig -v | grep gtest
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib64' given more than once
ldconfig: Can't stat /usr/libx32: No such file or directory
    libgtest1.so -> libgtest1.so
```

Result: `undefined reference to testing::*` for all the calls to the googletest library. It doesn't link. (i.e.: on all `ASSERT_*` etc..)
here's a sample:

```
CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/tests/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
/home/user/git_repos/projects/mylib/tests/main.cpp:33: multiple definition of `main'
CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/tests/src/main.cpp.o:/home/user/git_repos/projects/mylib/tests/src/main.cpp:4: first defined here
CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/tests/src/main.cpp.o: In function `A_B_Test::TestBody()':
/home/user/git_repos/projects/mylib/tests/src/main.cpp:3: undefined reference to `testing::Message::Message()'
/home/user/git_repos/projects/mylib/tests/src/main.cpp:3: undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::AssertHelper(testing::TestPartResult::Type, char const*, int, char const*)'
/home/user/git_repos/projects/mylib/tests/src/main.cpp:3: undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::operator=(testing::Message const&) const'
/home/user/git_repos/projects/mylib/tests/src/main.cpp:3: undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::~AssertHelper()'
/home/user/git_repos/projects/mylib/tests/src/main.cpp:3: undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::~AssertHelper()'
CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/tests/src/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
/home/user/git_repos/projects/mylib/tests/src/main.cpp:5: undefined reference to `testing::InitGoogleTest(int*, char**)'
```

etc...

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(mylib)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

set(SOURCE_FILES
    src/lib1.h
)

set(TEST_FILES
    tests/lib1.h
    tests/main.cpp
)

enable_testing()
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(mylib ${TEST_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Any help to get this thing working after having spent 3 full days of grind would be appreciated!

(btw, I'm using Clion)

Comment: I should add I've recently switch properly to Linux after much Window frustration so step-by-step instructions would probably be best in this case.

Comment: Please, edit your answer to include the full offending compilation command.

Comment: added. Also tried with a very basic project with 1 test and same sort of things happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have told CMake where to look for gtest header files, but not to link against the library. Since it is installed in a standard path `/usr/local/lib` it'll probably be enough to include a line like this in your CMakeLists.txt after the `add_executable` command:

```
target_link_libraries(mylib gtest)
```

or

```
target_link_libraries(mylib gtest_main gtest)
```

if you are not providing your own custom main function.

Note: *mylib* is a kind of misleading name for your test executable.

Answer (score 0):

You are not linking against libgtest.

A good example how to use cmake and goggle test can be found here: https://gist.github.com/oneamtu/3734295